# ${build.result} in Editable Email Notification Default Content

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson, email-ext, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to print ${build.result} in Editable Email Notification Default Content.
I receive the email with the content as ${build.result} instead of printing the actual result "SUCCESS".

Can any one suggest here if i am missing something.

Comment: Can't suggest what you are doing wrong if you don't show us what you are doing.

Comment: In Jenkins build execute section , i am just calling a unix command and then post build actions Editable email notification plugin - I am simply trying to print the result of the build..do you need any additional information?

Comment: If you are using pipeline, post the code. If not, post exactly what is configured in freestyle, or better yet, a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

On my last project we used this [template](https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/thumbnails/3604514/html.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1287057028000&api=v2) and it worked perfectly well.

The jelly for this template is [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html.jelly) and includes the build result and the appropriate Jenkins Orb icon.